# React-native stack navigation not showing right screen

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, stack-navigator

all, I am having a problem that my stack navigation is not showing any screen.
I have 'signup' and 'login' screens, and I build a stack navigator(which is the startStack) try to navigate between those two screens. But it doesn't work. when a user first come(if she hasn't logged in before), the 'login' screen should be shown.

Please help me out , I really appreciate , thank you.

### this is the App.js

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "react-native-gesture-handler";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";
import Login from "./screens/login";
import Signup from "./screens/signup";
import MyOrders from "./screens/myOrders";
import firebase from "firebase";
import StartNavigator from "./routes/startStack";

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    loggedIn: null,
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    
    var firebaseConfig = {
      apiKey: "AIzaSyASR4GAXSRGsiDhOTF_UsdqHzqHYcHPk_U",
      authDomain: "onlineorderportal-68a8f.firebaseapp.com",
      databaseURL: "https://onlineorderportal-68a8f.firebaseio.com",
      projectId: "onlineorderportal-68a8f",
      storageBucket: "onlineorderportal-68a8f.appspot.com",
      messagingSenderId: "658149255251",
      appId: "1:658149255251:web:37940844cdc5403e173ea6",
      measurementId: "G-KGQ1F2F3WE",
    };
    if (!firebase.apps.length) {
      firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    } else {
      firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
        if (user) {
          
          this.setState({ loggedIn: true });
        } else {
          
          this.setState({ loggedIn: false });
        }
      });
    }
  }

  renderContent = () => {
    switch (this.state.loggedIn) {
      case false:
        console.log("false case login");
        // return <Login />;
        // return <Signup />;
        return <StartNavigator />;

      case true:
        console.log("true case Navigator");
        return <MyOrders />;
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        
        {this.renderContent()}
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#FFFFFF",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
});

export default App;
```

### This is the startStack.js

```js
import React from "react";
import { createStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/stack";
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
import Login from "../screens/login";
import Signup from "../screens/signup";

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

function StartNavigator() {
  console.log("enter Start");
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Login">
        <Stack.Screen name="Signup" component={Signup} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={Login} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

export default StartNavigator;
```

When I try to return 'Login'  or 'Signup' separately, it correctly show the pages separately.

Thank you so much !!!

Answer (score 0):

You have created `StartNavigator`, which has only two screens 'Login' and 'Singup'. And you have set `initialRouteName` as 'Login'. So your 'App' component never called. So all the code that you written on App component never run. To work this add `App` component in your `StartNavigator` and set `initialRouteName` to app like below :

```js
import React from "react";
import { createStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/stack";
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
import Login from "../screens/login";
import Signup from "../screens/signup";
import App from "../app/path"; // import App here

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

function StartNavigator() {
  console.log("enter Start");
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Login">
        <Stack.Screen name="App" component={App} /> // add app component
        <Stack.Screen name="Signup" component={Signup} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={Login} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

export default StartNavigator;
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply !!!!! I tried , but still the same.   My console output 'enter Start', which means the app first run App.js, then run StartNavigator, but in StartNavigator, it doesnt return anything.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check conditions after receive data from the server?

what is the value of 'loggedIn'?

I think that the value of 'loggedIn' is not correct or your switch case is not working.

use console.log before doing any condition for sure that the value of 'loggedIn' is correct.

Comment: Thank you for your reply !!!!!!Yes, that is the problem. Now I use another method. I create new firebase.js in another folder, and the initialize happens in the new firebase.js